# How do I import WebSocketSubject in TypeScript?

Tags: rxjs, rxjs5

As suggested I installed using

```
npm install @reactivex/rxjs@5.0.0-beta.11
```

I can import almost everything this way:

```
import { Observable, Subscriber } from '@reactivex/rxjs';
```

but not WebSocketSubject. I've tried:

```
import { WebSocketSubject } from '@reactivex/rxjs';
import { WebSocketSubject } from '@reactivex/rxjs/observable/dom';
```

... and many other variations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`dom` is not a file, but a folder, so there will nothing to import :)
Try this one:

`import { WebSocketSubject } from '@reactivex/rxjs/src/observable/dom/WebSocketSubject';`

The import will give you the TypeScript source file, but I would recommend installing `rxjs@5.0.0-beta.11` rather than `@reactivex/rxjs` so you can do this:

`import { WebSocketSubject } from 'rxjs/observable/dom/WebSocketSubject';`

The above import will give you the `.js` file, not the `.ts` file. Autocompletion and all the good TypeScript stuff will still work, because the package has the `.d.ts` files!

*One more tip:* If you having problems finding the correct import path:

1. Go to `node_modules/[<organization_name>/]<package_name>` (the organization name is optional, they all start with `@`).
2. This is your starting point for all imports, from there you can append any folder/file path to the `[<organization_name>/]<package_name>` and the import *should* work.

**But** if you only point to the import statement to `[<organization_name>/]<package_name>` Typescript will pick up the real path to the import file from the `main` property of the `package.json`. Which in the case of `@reactivex/rxjs` points to `index.js` and that file again will do a `require('./dist/cjs/Rx')`. So when you do `@reactivex/rxjs` the path gets resolved to `node_modules/@reactivex/rxjs/dist/cjs/Rx.js`.

Hope this explaination wasn't to confusing, but the path resolution sometimes can be :-x

Comment: This is ugly but it does work! And its node_modules, not npm_modules :-)

Comment: Now I'm wondering why they suggest the syntax with the @ReactiveX if it's not necessary...

Comment: Sorry, typo there ... updated my answer. I did write it correctly in the second example! :D

Comment: @BillBarnes Do they? Think their readme doesn't :) https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs#es6-via-npm

Comment: It does for Typescript!